# SQL Выбрать из двух строк запись с последней датой

Tags: sql, oracle

|  | code | deal | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | type | 3 | 2019-02-06 16:52:00 |
| 2 | type | 4 | 2020-02-06 16:52:00 |
| 3 | type | 3 | 2020-02-06 17:52:00 |
| 4 | type | 4 | 2021-02-06 18:55:00 |

выбрать по двум одинаковым датам deal с последней датой
чтобы остались : 1,3,4

Comment: Я не уловил условия. Почему из двух строк? Как можно "выбрать по двум одинаковым датам deal с последней датой " если у них одинаковая дата?

Comment: Время deal разное. На одну deal за одну дату может быть несколько операций. Нужна последняя

Comment: *На одну deal за одну дату может быть несколько операций. Нужна последняя* Последняя - по какому критерию? при каком выражении сортировки?

Answer (score 1):

Это про оконные функции нужно почитать, а именно про ROW_NUMBER.

И примерно так это будет выглядеть:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY created ORDER BY deal) AS NUM
    FROM TableName
) AS Subquery
WHERE NUM = 1
```

Можно после deal дописать DESC, тогда по убыванию пронумеруется.

Comment: *PARTITION BY **deal**, created* - весьма сомнительно, сравните исходные и требуемый результат.

Comment: @Akina да, пока уберу. Просто условие не совсем понятно описано. Если по ТЗ, то вроде как deal нужен, если по "хочу так" - то нет). В целом вижу решение через оконные функции, а там уже сам под свои нужды каждый подстроит

Comment: Думаю, в выражении "выбрать по двум одинаковым датам deal с последней датой" под словом deal подразумевается вся запись о событии, которое автор также называет deal, a не одноимённое поле.